# Gulp doesn't compile anything anymore

Tags: node.js, gulp, taskmanager

Since today, `gulp` doesn't compile anything anymore.

The annoying part is, It doesn't even log errors. When running `gulp` on the command line, as I do every day, I get the standard log from my server starting up. It even logs my watch commands as I change JavaScript or CSS files, saying it's executing the associated tasks.

Gulp is then configured to output files into directories, but they never get compiled. I checked another project in which I use different Gulp files, nothing compiles anymore.

So, I uninstalled Gulp using `npm uninstall gulp -g`, uninstalled it locally using `npm uninstall --save-dev gulp`, did all the installation again (resulting in global CLI version 3.8.10).

Nothing.

I encountered a crazy amount of errors using `grunt`, `gulp`, `node` etc., but I can't seem to fix this one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/145

Comment: Your link did the trick. This problem appeared after npm update was executed. Gulp seems to compile and does not give any errors whatsoever. The above link from @Heikki fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Issue has been fixed now. No tricks needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments in my question point to a temporary issue with an updated gulp version. No longer needed.